# How to Edit Datagrid Records and also in database

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

this is my code for loading the data from database to datagrid

```
Private Sub Records_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0; Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "\BackUp\Database3.Accdb;"
    Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim tables As DataTableCollection
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource

    MyConn = New OleDbConnection
    MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
    ds = New DataSet
    tables = ds.Tables
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [userinfo] ORDER BY ID", MyConn)
    da.Fill(ds, "userinfo") 'Change items to your database name
    Dim cb = New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    Dim view As New DataView(tables(0))
    source1.DataSource = view
    DataGridView1.DataSource = view

End Sub


Private Sub btnCreate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCreate.Click
    If RequiredEntry() = True Then
        Return
    End If
    Try
        Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0; Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "\BackUp\Database3.Accdb;")

        If cn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then cn.Open()

        Dim sSQL As String = "insert into [userinfo]([username],[password],[FirstName],[LastName],[Account]) values(@username,@password,@FirstName,@LastName,@Account)"

        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sSQL, cn)


        ' UserName
        If txtPassword.Text = txtConfirm.Text Then
            Dim username As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@username", OleDbType.VarWChar, 50)
            username.Value = txtUser.Text.ToString()
            cmd.Parameters.Add(username)
        Else
            MsgBox("Password not matched")

        End If

        'password
        Dim password As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@password", OleDbType.VarWChar, 50)
        password.Value = txtPassword.Text.ToString()
        cmd.Parameters.Add(password)


        'First Name
        Dim FirstName As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@FirstName", OleDbType.VarWChar, 50)
        FirstName.Value = txtFirstName.Text.ToString()
        cmd.Parameters.Add(FirstName)


        ' Last Name
        Dim LastName As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@LastName", OleDbType.VarWChar, 50)
        LastName.Value = txtLastName.Text.ToString()
        cmd.Parameters.Add(LastName)

        'Account

        Dim Account As OleDbParameter = New OleDbParameter("@Account", OleDbType.VarWChar, 50)
        Account.Value = cboAccount.GetItemText(cboAccount.SelectedItem)
        cmd.Parameters.Add(Account)



        If cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() Then
            cn.Close()
            MessageBox.Show("New User is Added successfully.", "Record Saved")
            Call clear()
            Me.Hide()
            FileMaintenance.Show()


        Else
            MsgBox("New User Addition Failed ", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Addition Failed")
            Return
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        Exit Sub
    End Try
End Sub
Private Sub NewUser_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    e.SuppressKeyPress = e.Control
    If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        SendKeys.Send("{tab}")
    End If

End Sub
```

and this is my for delete

```
Private Sub cmdDelete_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdDelete.Click
    Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0; Data Source=" & My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath.ToString() & "\BackUp\Database3.Accdb;"
    Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim tables As DataTableCollection
    Dim source1 As New BindingSource
    Dim rows As String


    Try
        MyConn = New OleDbConnection
        MyConn.ConnectionString = connString
        ds = New DataSet
        tables = (ds.Tables)
        rows = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("Delete * from [userinfo] where ID=" & rows, MyConn)
        da.Fill(ds, "userinfo")
        Records_Load(sender, e)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("cannot delete empty records")
    End Try
```

how can i edit my data from datagrid view as well in my database
also how can i lock the datagrid from entering fields accidentally

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very wrong.  You're retrieving the data correctly in the first place but then you're inserting and deleting incorrectly.

The idea is that you use one data adapter for all four operations, i.e. select, insert, update and delete.  That's why it has `SelectCommand`, `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand` properties.  You call `Fill` and it executes the SQL in the `SelectCommand` to retrieve data into a `DataTable`.  You are then supposed to make all the changes you want, i.e. insert, update and delete, to the data in that `DataTable`.  When you're done, you call `Update` on the data adapter and it will execute the SQL in the `InsertCommand`, `UpdateCommand` and `DeleteCommand` as required to save all the changes back to the database.  Here's an example I wrote a long time ago:

```
Private connection As New SqlConnection("connection string here")
Private adapter As New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT ID, Name, Quantity, Unit FROM StockItem", _
                                      connection)
Private table As New DataTable

Private Sub InitialiseDataAdapter()
    Dim delete As New SqlCommand("DELETE FROM StockItem WHERE ID = @ID", Me.connection)
    Dim insert As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO StockItem (Name, Quantity, Unit) VALUES (@Name, @Quantity, @Unit)", Me.connection)
    Dim update As New SqlCommand("UPDATE StockItem SET Name = @Name, Quantity = @Quantity, Unit = @Unit WHERE ID = @ID", Me.connection)

    delete.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "ID")

    insert.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, "Name")
    insert.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Float, 8, "Quantity")
    insert.Parameters.Add("@Unit", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10, "Unit")

    update.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100, "Name")
    update.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", SqlDbType.Float, 8, "Quantity")
    update.Parameters.Add("@Unit", SqlDbType.VarChar, 10, "Unit")
    update.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int, 4, "ID")

    Me.adapter.DeleteCommand = delete
    Me.adapter.InsertCommand = insert
    Me.adapter.UpdateCommand = update

    Me.adapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey
End Sub

Private Sub GetData()
    'Retrieve the data.
    Me.adapter.Fill(Me.table)

    'The table can be used here to display and edit the data.
    'That will most likely involve data-binding but that is not a data access issue.
End Sub

Private Sub SaveData()
    'Save the changes.
    Me.adapter.Update(Me.table)
End Sub
```

Note that this example was written for SQL Server but you simply swap out all the `SqlClient` types for `OleDb` types and it works for Access.

If you want to save changes immediately for some reason then you simply call `Update` after each change.

By the way, your connection string should be written like this:

```
Dim connString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Ace.Oledb.12.0; Data Source=|DataDirectory|\BackUp\Database3.Accdb;"
```

Comment: sorry i have a mixed of sql and oledb tutorial. will use your code and change it to oledb. thanks for it and will comment here again if i have a problem. thanks again